# ¿Se puede cambiar el paquete de una aplicación android?

Tags: java, android

he intentado cambiar el package de la aplicación de WhatsApp con ApkEditor  Pro (aplicación android), ApkTool (programa windows), ApkManager (programa windows), y otros decompiladores, pero la aplicación se daña, una vez intente entrar en NotePad y reemplazar todos los com.whatsapp por el package que quiero pero esta vez ya no era error de analisis lo que me decía, sino que al abrir la aplicación se detenía.

Quiero saber si hay alguna forma de editar el package de esta aplicación sin dañarla, ya sea editando uno por uno (aunque son como 20.000 en un wamod) quiero poder cambiar esto...

Comment: Hay muchas personas que cambian el package name de los WaMods, ejemplo gbmods (GBWhatsApp), jimtech (WhatsApp Plus), Yousef Al Basha (YoWhatsApp), y muchos mods desconocidos, pienso que algo debe haber para facilitar el trabajo

Answer (score -1):

En este caso la API usada por `Whatsapp` tiene asignados permisos definidos para su `packagename`, esto es muy común en las API, si cambias el `packagename` seguramente no funcionaria correctamente ya que no te permitiría acceder a funcionalidades de la API.

Además `Whatsapp` es una aplicación en donde puedes compartir imágenes, video, audio, por tal motivo puede acceder al almacenamiento de la aplicación tanto para guardar y enviar archivos (crea archivos temporales) y el guardado de los archivos se realiza dentro del almacenamiento externo en el folder definido por el packagename que es com.whatsapp, esto podría realizarse en otro directorio pero deberías revisar el código.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Además de esto la aplicación usa servicios:

```
<service android:name=".messaging.MessageService">
</service>
<service android:name=".c2dm.C2DMRegistrar">
</service>
<service android:name=".ExternalMediaManager">
</service>
...
...
```

usa Providers, donde tiene autorización el paquete de la aplicación `com.whatsapp.....`:

```
    <provider android:name=".contact.ContactProvider" android:exported="false" android:authorities="com.whatsapp.provider.contact">
    </provider>
    <provider android:name="com.whatsapp.MediaProvider" android:exported="false" android:multiprocess="true" android:authorities="com.whatsapp.provider.media">
    </provider>
```

Sería un arduo trabajo cambiar el `packagename` pero seguramente no funcionaría adecuadamente.

Comment: **CP Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.